# How to use netty in webapp for permanent TCP remote connection?

Tags: netty, ejb-3.1

Because of some legacy requirements, we need to keep an open TCP socket to a legacy system and exchange some messages with it asynchronously. We have a webapp that receives requests from the web, and currently a separate Java app that includes Netty which does legacy communication.

We would now like to somehow embed Netty directly into the webapp package, so that the socket is started when the webapp runs, and so that webapp (or EJB) and interact with netty Channels etc.

Do you have an idea how to do this?

So what I wish to accomplish is throw away JMS queues that we are right now using for integrating netty/legacy part of functionality with the web-facing functionality, in other words I wish to significantly simplify the architecture so that only webapp+EJBs are used, but not JMS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the Servlet container you run has no `SecurityManager`configured, you can start a Netty application as a part of your web application.

First off, write a `ServletContextListener` implementation that is notified when your web application is started or stopped by the Servlet container.  You can start and stop your Netty application there.  You also should probably update the `web.xml` so that the Servlet container picks it up.

To make the Netty application interact with your web application (e.g. send a message to the legacy system via the Netty application), you'll have to expose your Netty application to your Web application.  This is usually done via a singleton.

Because every operation in Netty is asynchronous, you might experience some 'impedance mismatch' between your web application and the Netty application.  Typically, the web application will ask the Netty application send a request to the legacy system and wait until the Netty applications notifies when the response is received from the legacy system.

To deal with this scenario, you can usually use a data structure such as `BlockingQueue` - after sending a request, the web application waits until the queue has an element, and the Netty application will add the response object to the queue to notify the web application.

If you are using Netty 4, you might want to take a look at the `io.netty.util.concurrent.Future/Promise` classes which are also a very useful construct for such a scenario.

Comment: Hi there Trustin. How would I solve the problem of communication with the legacy system being async in nature? I.e. Web requests is received, and I need to return a sync response -> but in the meantime netty (deployed as you suggested above) has to contact the legacy server and receive the response that I can read in the servlet. Do I need to poll for result in servlet?